# Extract ticker and Company Name from website

Tags: excel, powerquery

Is it possible to extract the ticker symbol and the Company Name from Yahoo Finance?
The ticker symbol is easy as it is on many of the yh tables. The company name is a bit trickier.

Thanks in advance.

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/")),
    Data2 = Source{2}[Data]
in
    Data2
```

Comment: My tip would be to sign up for the API, much easier ... https://www.yahoofinanceapi.com/ ... it gives you that information and more in a much easier to deal with structure than pulling from the site itself.

Comment: I can't seem to access the yahoo finance API this evening.  Depending on your overall needs, there are others, including alphavantage which has a free API for limited use and paid versions for more intensive usage.  You can easily get the full name from a ticker.